# What is => in asp.net core MVC?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When i open my default model class (ErrorViewModel) i found **=>** operator. What is that actually ? What is the use of it ?

```
using System;

namespace MvcCoreApp.Models
{
    public class ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
    }
}
```

What is the use of this **=>** operator here ?

Comment: (Expression-bodied members)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members]

Comment: @tchelidze Your link has no data, And i searched for 'Expression-bodied members' and got enough details. Thanks